# how can i extract a specific element from the html

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to extract an element from the html with the function that I have.

```
document.querySelector('#get_html').addEventListener('click', function () {
    var url = document.querySelector('#url_html');



    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url.value);
    request.send();

    request.onload = function() {
       console.log(request.response);
    };

})
```

I have an input where I put the url of a page and the function brings me the complete html of the page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="offer">
           <div class="card"></div>
           <div class="card"></div>
           <div class="card"></div>
           <div class="card"></div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

this is the html that it throws me, now what I want is to extract that div element with the offer class

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`parseFromString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) to get the string from the response into a format you can query the DOM.

```js
var responseText = `<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
      <meta charset="UTF-8">
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
      <title>Document</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <div class="offer">
           <div class="card"></div>
           <div class="card"></div>
           <div class="card"></div>
           <div class="card"></div>
      </div>
    </body>
</html>`;

const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(responseText, "text/html");
console.log(doc.querySelector(".offer"));
```